# How to make app windows go full screen in current Space?

Tags: macos, big-sur

I really like the new way that macos tiles windows, but what I don't like is that it always puts the windows in a new Space. So I end up having to navigate to the new space, while the original is left doing nothing. Is there a way that I can tile windows (i.e. holding down the green window button and selecting "tile left") without it automatically moving it to a new Space? It's such a weird implementation. On Windows 10, you can easily do it by just dragging to the sides.